# How to solve my "Cannot resolve symbol" java error?

Tags: java, package

I've got this external library including class `StdRandom`. When I call this class from my src folder, then it is recognized, no problem :

[image]

However, moving (and refactoring) my class with the call to `StdRandom`, makes it so it does **not** recognize the call to `StdRandom` anymore :

[image]

How do I make it so it still recognizes the class, even inside a package?

Comment: For resolving, you can either refer to the class by its full package and class name, or import the file/class in the new location

Comment: Which external library is that class in?

Comment: @f1sh stdlib.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access class A from class B, one of the following has to be true:

- Both classes are in the same package
- Class B has an "import" statement for class A. (Note that, if class A is in the default package - i. e. it has no "package" declaration in its first line - no other class can ever import it, which is why you should never ever have classes in the default package.)
- Any time class A is referenced, you do it with a fully qualified name - i. e. "the.package.the.class.is.in.A" instead of just "A".

Judging from your screenshots, I can only assume that StdRandom is in a JAR file you access as an external library, and that it is also in the default package - meaning that you will only be able to refer to it from classes that are also in the default package.

edit: OP solved the problem by unpacking the StdRandom class from its JAR and refactoring it to use another package.

Comment: So in the end, I decompressed the Java files from the .jar and manually refactored them in some new package... For completeness, could you add this to your answer, since it does not answer my main question.

Comment: Sure, here you go